Set custom Bootstrap invalid/valid messages
I have made a login/register form using react.js/bootstrap and in the register form i have 4 inputs. One for username, one for email, and 2 for password (1 password and 1 for confirmation purposes), i want to show a message if the 2 passwords dont match, sth like passwords dont match.
I tried adding the invalid-feedback  boostrap class after checking if the 2 password inputs but it doesnt work as expected Here is the code i am using :
   function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const form = e.target;
    passwordChecker();


    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        handleLoginClick();
        reset();
        console.log("Form submitted successfully");
    } else {
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }
  }
function passwordChecker(){
    const confirmPasswordField = document.querySelector("#invalidpassword1");
    if (isRegistering && password !== checkPassword) {
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
        confirmPasswordField.classList.add("invalid-feedback"); 
        console.log("passwords dont match")
    } else {
        confirmPasswordField.classList.remove("invalid-feedback");
        console.log("passwords  match")
    }
  }


<div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input 
                      type="password" 
                      className="form-control" 
                      id="registerPassword" 
                      placeholder="Enter your password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
                      required 
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="registerPassword">Password</label>
                    <div className='invalid-feedback' id='invalidpassword2'>Please fill out this field</div>
                 
  <div className="form-floating mb-3">
                    <input 
                      type="password" 
                      className="form-control" 
                      id="confirmPassword" 
                      placeholder="Confirm your password"
                      value={checkPassword}
                      onChange={(e) => setCheckPassword(e.target.value)}
                      required
                    />
                    <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div id='invalidpassword1'>Passwords do not match</div> 
                  </div>

new code I tried
<div id='invalidpassword1' className='invalid-feedback'>{checkPassword==='' ? 'Please fill out this field' : 'Passwords do not match'}</div>

now the right message pops up but still the equation doesnt work and when the passwords don't match it shows up correct

You need to manually set input field validity with setCustomValidity()
So, get the input field and set its validity to something (for example, a space to avoid browser displaying the message, and instead only showing BS feedback):
if (isRegistering && password !== checkPassword) {
    form.classList.add('was-validated');
    confirmPasswordField.classList.add("invalid-feedback"); 
    console.log("passwords dont match")

    const input = document.querySelector('#confirmPassword');
    input.setCustomValidity(" ");                
    input.reportValidity();


According to the bootstrap docs, the invalid/valid custom feedback messages must be contained inside a <form> with the novalidate attribute.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/validation/#custom-styles

yea i have already added that but I didnt post it my  bad          

Can you give an example of what's not working as expected?

Yes i have updated the code i sent at first, I am checking the 2 passwords to see if they are the same and as expceted i get the msg "passwords dont match" but the input acts like its correct it gets green etc. So I suppose the class is not added or sth like that because  I dont get any more warning in the console

I don't believe forms check if passwords match by default, right now passwordChecker() is only being called if the form validation fails. So you could have non-matching passwords but form.checkValidity() still returns true.

Yes you are right I called the passwordChecker at the start of handleSubmit and it should work now but still, when i just place 1 character in the confirmpassword it instantly gets valid, instead of that i want it to be equal to first password

I mean i could have 5 characters in the first input and 2 at the second and its correct when it shoudlnt
